# Weird highlighting when navigating vimrc

Tags: colorscheme, highlight

So I recently downloaded [Jellybeans.vim](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim), and it was working fine until today when I opened `.vimrc` and to add something to the bottom of the file I pressed `G` , this happened:

[image]

Then I pressed `gg` to go the top of the file and this happened:

[image]

Then I went down line by line and all was okay :

[image]

The weird part is that this only happens in `.vimrc`. Everything else (even `.bashrc`) works normally.

I use WSL in HyperTerm. When I tried during the same by running WSL in CMD Prompt it worked just fine. Also, in Hyper other .vim scripts work fine too.

Any ideas on why this is happening ?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is usually a term issue, though its odd it only happens for one file. A couple things for you to investigate: is the environment variable TERM set correctly in and out of vim? Are you messing with any of the terminal control codes in vim? Does this happen in any other files (I would check some other vimscript files)? Does it help if you force a redraw with Ctrl-L or `:redraw!`? Are there any special character in your vimrc that might be interpreted as escape codes?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes I checked and it is most probably a term issue. I use WSL in HyperTerm. When I tried during the same by running WSL in CMD Prompt it worked just fine. Also, in Hyper other .vim scripts work fine too. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Try `set t_ut=` to clear it as a workaround, see https://superuser.com/q/1534358/879179

Comment: Also: https://superuser.com/q/1526515/879179

Comment: Seems to be a common problem on Windows... Consider upgrading all the components on your Windows setup (WSL, Vim itself, HyperTerm, etc.) to see if it's fixed... If it isn't, try the `set t_ut=` workaround to disable BCE, but that means scrolling will be slightly slower than it should.

Comment: Let me know if that works... Happy to turn it into an answer if it does!

Comment: @filbranden It Works! Yes scrolling is slow. The green highlighting appears for just a fraction of a second and then everything turns back to normal. Thank you so much !